# WebPack, Polyfills, RxJs, Incorrect Chunk Order

Tags: import, webpack, rxjs, polyfills, html-webpack-plugin

I've been working on a Vue project and have everything set up so that it has been working well so far. I have `WebPack (2)` configured with the entry points `Polyfills` and `App`, and `Vendor` as a common chunk output.

Normally `Webpack`/`HtmlWebpackPlugin` puts the `<script>` tags in the right order (`Polyfills`, `Vendor`, `App`).

However, when I `import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'` in my `App` entry point, it rearranges the `<script>` tags in the incorrect order (`Vendor`, `App`, `Polyfills`).

I don't know why this is happening, I assume there's something in `RxJs` that `Webpack`/`HtmlWebpackPlugin` deems more important to bring in before the `Polyfills` (I assume that's how it knows to bring in `Polyfills` first otherwise).

Should I include part of `RxJs` in my `polyfills`? I know I can force `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to output in a certain order, but `RxJs` is the only thing that seems to have forced it into a different order.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding your polyfills-entry-point to your app-file with an import? How does it behave then?